# Hide a button in Spring Boot/Thymeleaf application if not logged in

Tags: java, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I'm trying to hide a button in the header of my Spring Boot application in the following way with my markup:

```
<!-- Is not logged in, so don't show "Log In" -->
<li sec:authorize="!isAuthenticated()">
    <a href="/login" th:href="@{/login}" class="btn-login">Log In</a>
</li>\
```

Is this not correct? I'm using the Thymeleaf templating engine.

Comment: Please check if your configuration is correct https://github.com/thymeleaf/thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity and also check if the dialect `SpringSecurityDialect` is added for `sec` tag to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add Spring Security Dialect in spring boot app for `sec` attribute to work,

```
@Configuration
public class ThymeleafConfig {

    @Bean
    public SpringSecurityDialect springSecurityDialect(){
        return new SpringSecurityDialect();
    }
}
```

If you have a Spring Security Dialect, then you can try,

```
<!-- Show login link only for anonymous users -->
<div sec:authorize="isAnonymous()">
    <a href="/login" th:href="@{/login}" class="btn-login">Log In</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use simple if's:
http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/2.1/usingthymeleaf.html#simple-conditionals-if-and-unless

But you have to put the objects, you use in the if's, before into the (Spring) Model

Comment: I'll mark this as the accepted answer because it answers the question. Unfortunately for me, I must be missing something in my Users object model and/or web security config.